# Plotting a 2D colour map in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot a map given a text file with numbers in the following config:

float column (x)   float column (y)   float column (z)

x and y are numbers that change every 0.05 while Z can be a positive number. My idea is to have a board, like a chess board, with squares of x and y of size 0.05 (since x and y change every 0.05) and then use the z to just colour. I don't want the map to be in 3D but just in 2D. For this I have the following code:

```
set terminal png size 2000,2000

#set size ratio -1
set xtics 0,0.05
set ytics 0,0.05

#set grid ytics mytics  # draw lines for each ytics and mytics
set mytics 2           # set the spacing for the mytics
set mxtics 2           # set the spacing for the mytics
set grid front mxtics mytics lw 1.5 lt -1 lc rgb 'black' # enable the grid

set xrange [0:.65]
set yrange [0:.65]
#set cbrange [7:50]

set palette model HSV defined ( 0 0 1 1, 1 1 1 1 )

set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"

set key at 64,64 font "Times-New-Roman,18" textcolor rgb "black"
set output "output.png"
plot "data.dat" using 1:2:14 w image
```

This code was working for other text files where x and y numbers are positive integers that change every unit, but here is like if the map weere tilted, if gnuplot were using also the z direction... what is wrong with it?

Example of my result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this problem, the problem was there were some rows not consecutive. This is: if x and y are between 0.05 and 0.6, if you have:

```
> 0.05   0.05   zz
> 0.05   0.10   zz
> 0.05   0.15   zz
> 0.05   0.20   zz
> 0.05   0.25   zz
> **0.1   0.05   zz
> 0.1   0.20   zz**
> 0.1   0.25   zz
> 0.15   0.05   zz
> 0.15   0.10   zz
> 0.15   0.15   zz
> 0.15   0.20   zz
> 0.15   0.25   zz
```

Then it will give you this error. You need the rows in between the **. If you don't have values for those z, fill the x and y and put for the z: "NaN" (without quotes). If gnuplot does not accept it, then put in the script this line: set datafile missing "NaN"

PS. my numbers were in scientific notation